# Bash script not resolving symlinks

Tags: bash

I have the following in one of my bash scripts:

```
PID_PATH="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )/../pids/" && pwd )"

#...

if [ -e $PID_PATH/the_file.pid ]; then
    echo "the_file was found!"
else
    echo "the_file was not found!"
fi
```

When I echo PID_PATH, it's 100% correct, but the if statement keeps evaluating to false? The pids folder itself is a symlink, and I'm suspecting that Ubuntu doesn't like that in the if statement.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

And what's weird is, that when I run the if statement on it's own, with the PID_PATH variable, as a separate script, (in the same path), it works 100%?

Comment: Add double quotes arounf variables !

Comment: What are you eliding with `#...`? Could the value of `PID_PATH` be changed before the test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem weirdly enough was fixable by adding a short delay before checking if the .pid file exists.

```
PID_PATH="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )/../pids/" && pwd )"

#...

sleep 0.3 
if [ -e $PID_PATH/the_file.pid ]; then
    echo "the_file was found!" 
else
    echo "the_file was not found!"
fi
```

Must be to do with the file still being created, while wanting to check for it a bit too soon, a typical racing condition issue.

Answer (score 0):

Some possibilities:

- Does `PID_PATH` contain any spaces or other `[^a-zA-Z0-9._-]` characters? You should double quote `$PID_PATH/the_file.pid` to avoid whitespace expansion.
- Have you tried `echo "$PID_PATH"` on the line before the `if`?
- Are you sure you didn't simplify away some code in the example which could be relevant?
- Do you get any error messages? Try using `set -o errexit -o nounset -o pipefail` at the top of the file.
- Is the symlink broken at some point during execution?

Comment: In addition to the above, put `set -x` in your script to trace execution so you can see exactly what that `if` statement is checking...